# JavaScript simple search - how to display result on new page?

Tags: javascript, search

In the assignment we were supposed to build a simple search feature using an event listener on the search button. So there is a file called store.js, with a global array of objects to simulate a database of albums. When the user searches for an artist, it should display the result on a new page. I got it to loop through the array, get the result, and show it on the page.
The thing I can't figure out is how to open a "search results" page, and display the result there. If I save the result to a global variable and try to display it on the new page, it says "undefined".
Just to note, this is a beginner client-side JS class, so there shouldn't be any "backend" languages needed.
I would appreciate any hints, or criticisms.

This is from the assignment instructions:

> 1. Create a file called search.js.
> 2. Create an event listener in the search.js script that is handled by a function called search that handles the onclick event for the
>      submit button for the search.
> 3. When I type an artist name (I'm only going to search by artist name right now), in the search box and hit submit, your search
>      function should loop through the fake database of albums in the
>      store.js file. Open a new page and display the results in a list on
>      that page. You will need to use dom manipulation for this part.

Thank you!

HTML:

```
<button id="searchButton">Search</button>

<div id="displayResult"></div>
```

JS:

```
//Search
var result = "Nothing found!";

function displaySearch() {
    "use strict";

    var displayResult = document.getElementById("displayResult");

    window.open("search.html") //How do I display the result in this page?

    displayResult.style.display = "block";
    displayResult.innerHTML = result;
}

function doSearch() {
    "use strict";

    var searchField = document.getElementById("searchField").value;

    for (var i = 0; i < db.length; i++) {
        if (db[i].artist.toUpperCase() === searchField.toUpperCase()) {
            result = db[i].artist;
        }
    }

    displaySearch();

}

function search() {
    "use strict";

    var searchButton = document.getElementById("searchButton");
    searchButton.addEventListener("click", doSearch, false);
}

window.addEventListener("load", search, false);
```

FAKE DB:

```
var db = []; //array of fake album database

function Album(id, title, artist, price, relDate, qty, tracks) {
    "use strict";
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.price = price;
    this.relDate = relDate;
    this.qty = qty;
    this.tracks = tracks;
    db.push(this);
}

var album1 = new Album("01", "Animals", "Pink Floyd", 18.99, "01/23/1977", 1000, ["1. Pigs on the Wing 1", "2. Dogs", "3. Pigs (Three Different Ones)", "4. Sheep", "5. Pigs on the Wing 2"]);

var album2 = new Album("02", "Cosmic Slop", "Funkadelic", 19.99, "07/09/1973", 500, ["1. Nappy Dugout", "2. You Can’t Miss What You Can’t Measure", "3. March to the Witch’s Castle", "4. Let’s Make It Last", "5. Cosmic Slop", "6. No Compute", "7. This Broken Heart", "8. Trash A-Go-Go", "9. Can’t Stand the Strain"]);

var album3 = new Album("03", "Ghost Reveries", "Opeth", 14.99, "08/29/2005", 1500, ["1. Ghost of Perdition", "2. The Baying of the Hounds", "3. Beneath the Mire", "4. Atonement", "5. Reverie/Harlequin Forest", "6. Hours of Wealth", "7. The Grand Conjuration", "8. Isolation Years"]);
```

Comment: This is a school assignment and you want us to solve it for you? What will you learn then? :)

Comment: I already submitted the assignment. I don't want it solved, I want to learn how to do it. I am asking for HINTS, not solutions! "I would appreciate any hints, or criticisms."

Why would I copy/paste the exact assignment instructions and my real name? My professor isn't stupid.

Comment: Ok ok I was kidding. What you need is to acces the `document` of the opened window and operate there. I don't know what `search.html` has, you could modify that DOM content or create a blank page and create the results in it. :)

Comment: could you give some sample data to be searched?

Comment: Edited with the fake db

Answer (score 0):

```
//Search
var result = "Nothing found!";

function displaySearch() {
    var displayResult = document.getElementById("displayResult");
     window.history.pushState({},"Test","search.html");//fake redirect
    document.body.innerHTML = result;//clear all content (trough overriding) + add results
}

function doSearch() {
    var searchField = document.getElementById("searchField").value;

    result=db.filter(el=>el.artist.toUpperCase()===searchField.toUpperCase()).map(el=>el.artist).join("<br>");
    //     filter trough than get the artists name and create a html string out of that array
    displaySearch();

}

function search() {
    document.getElementById("searchButton").addEventListener("click", doSearch, false);
}

window.addEventListener("load", search, false);
```

Unlike your question asked, i provided a complete solution. But as you were quite right, i thought thats okay. Ive also added some ES6 stuff wich you cannot know from school, so this answer will be useless concerning cheating. Having two pages doesnt make sense if the application is completely serverless. Thats why ive implemented a url change, there mustnt be a search.html.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work.


 search.js:7 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///E:/Dropbox/School/COP2803/assignment_3/search.html' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file:///E:/Dropbox/School/COP2803/assignment_3/index2.html'.
    at displaySearch (file:///E:/Dropbox/School/COP2803/assignment_3/js/search.js:7:20)
    at HTMLButtonElement.doSearch (file:///E:/Dropbox/School/COP2803/assignment_3/js/search.js:16:5)
displaySearch @ search.js:7
doSearch @ search.js:16

Answer (score 0):

When you call `window.open` it will return a reference to the window just opened. From there you can get that window's `document` object and write to it / update it as you wish.

I can't give you a runnable snippet because window.open is forbidden in that context, but you can simply run the following in your browser console:

```
var newWin = window.open('', '') //a blank page
newWin.document.write('HI THERE!')
```

That is what was missing in your code. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got feedback from the professor.
He wanted us to use sessionStorage to pass the search result to another page.

Thanks everyone who tried to help.

http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Seriously? Why not simply display it? It doesnt make sense to me.